# Construction of circular arcs through vertices of a rectangle, tangent to the diagonals?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I know that you can construct the tangent line to a circle, for example, but my question is in the reverse order:

> If one draws a rectangle, can you use a compass and a straightedge to construct the circular arcs that pass through pairs of adjacent corners while being tangent to the rectangle's diagonals? Basically, can you make this shape?

***(note: this image is an approximation, and is not the true construction I am looking for)***

[image]

Comment: Construct the perpendiculars to the diagonals at the vertices.

Comment: Wow! So simple. Thanks!